# Symfony3.1 OptionresolverException when using LDAP-HTTP-Auth and default Symfony LDAP-Configuration

Tags: php, active-directory, symfony-3.1

I'm trying to build an application with symfony 3.1 which authenticates against an ActiveDirectory. I took the Configuration from http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/ldap.html and changed the company specific parameters. Also I installed the Symfony\Ldap - Component via Composer.
First I want to use the HTTP-Basic-Auth Mechanism with LDAP, provided by Symfony.
The Browser asks the username and the password, but when you submit both, this Exception shows up:

```
The options "optReferrals", "useSsl", "useStartTls" do not exist. Defined options are: "connection_string", "debug", "encryption", "host", "options", "port", "referrals", "version"
```

Why does this Exception appear?

security.yml:

```
security:
access_control:
    - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_USER }
# http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
providers:
   in_memory:
        memory: ~
   ad_ldap:
    ldap:
      service: ldap
      base_dn: DC=company,DC=de
      search_dn: "CN=ldap-user,OU=Service-Accounts,OU=Administration,DC=company,DC=de"
      search_password: password
      default_roles: ROLE_USER
      uid_key: sAMAccountName            
firewalls:
    # disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    login_firewall:
        pattern:   ^/login$
        anonymous: ~
    main:
        #provider: in_memory
        anonymous: ~
        # activate different ways to authenticate

        # http_basic: ~
        # http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#a-configuring-how-your-users-will-authenticate

        # form_login: ~
        # http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/form_login_setup.html
        provider: ad_ldap
        pattern:  ^/
        logout:
            path:   logout
            target: /
        http_basic_ldap:
            service: ldap
            dn_string: 'uid={username},OU=Users,OU=Resources,DC=company,DC=de'
```

services.yml:

```
services:
    ldap:
       class: 'Symfony\Component\Ldap\LdapClient'
       arguments:
            - dc.company.de   # host
            - 389         # port
            - 3           # version
            - false       # SSL
            - true        # TLS
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that this is a bug in Symfony. For further information see: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/19008